# Dependencies outside jar Gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, jar

I am using Eclipse with Gradle, And I have to say Gradle is far easier than Maven. However I want to create a jar of my project with its dependencies located in a folder `outside` the jar called `libs`.

The examples I have found are about creating a `fatjar` meaning embedding the dependencies inside the jar, not outside the jar.

I'm using Eclipse Neon with Gradle 3.3.

Comment: Please consider http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

The examples you have found are right. If you really need your final archive to be jar, then you either have to embed the jars into a single one (uberjar or fatjar) or preferably publish the libraries in `/libs` somewhere, probably as maven artifacts (for dev purposes, maybe just to local repository),  and refer to them in your `dependencies { ... }` block.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create a custom task to unpack your libs next to the built Artifact.

Then depend on the jar task to deploy all your libs next to the jar, and make sure it runs after implicitly.

```
task someTask (dependsOn: jar){

from(configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) })
into {where you want it}

}
```